# Dispatching function does not "always" update the props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my sample todo list app, I am trying to update all todos after creating or removing one so I can re-render the list component after changes. It sometimes updates the todos, but sometimes does not. I could not figure out the reason.

I am using Redux and Thunk. When a button is clicked, I dispatch "Create requested", then make async request, then dispatch "Create received", then dispatch `fetchAllTodos()`, and then catch "Create failed".

In the `HomePage` container, I pass `this.props.todos` to `TodoList` component as props. The problem I have is that it sometimes re-renders the list component with the changes, but sometimes does not. I also figured out in `componentWillReceiveProps` method that I do not get the updated props. Could this be related to a server issue or is it something I am doing wrong?

Here is how I set up the store:

```
const middlewares = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
  }),
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
```

Here is the `fetchAllTodos()` method:

```
export function fetchAllTodos() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ALL_TODOS_REQUESTED
    });

    console.log('todos requested');

    return SuperFetch.get('/todos')
      .then(todos => {
        console.log('todos received ' + todos.length);
        dispatch({
          type: ALL_TODOS_RECEIVED,
          payload: todos
        })
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch({
        type: ALL_TODOS_FAILED,
        payload: error
      }));
  }
```

Here is `createTodo()` method:

```
export function createTodo(description) {
  const body = {description: description};

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_TODO_REQUESTED
    });

    return SuperFetch.post(`/todos`, body)
      .then(todo => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_TODO_RECEIVED,
        payload: todo
      }))
      .then(dispatch(fetchAllTodos()))
      .catch(error => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_TODO_FAILED,
        payload: error
      }));
  }
}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
export default function todoReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ALL_TODOS_REQUESTED:
      state = Object.assign({}, state, {todosLoading: true, todosError: null});
      break;
    case ALL_TODOS_RECEIVED:
      state = Object.assign({}, state, {todos: action.payload, todosLoading: false, todosError: null});
      break;
    case ALL_TODOS_FAILED:
      state = Object.assign({}, state, {todos: null, todosLoading: false, todosError: action.payload});
      break;
    // rest of it
  return state
```

In `HomePage`, I just map state to props, and then pass the todos if they exist:

```
render() {

    const {todos, error, loading} = this.props;

    // if error part

    if (todos && !loading) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container text>
            <TodoInput/>
          </Container>

          <Container style={{marginTop: '1em'}} text>
            <TodoList todos={todos}/>
          </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

Might the problem be related to the fact that I am dispatching the action in `TodoInput` component and trying to update the `TodoList`? If so, how can I fix the problem because I do not want to dispatch all actions on the same `HomePage` container.

Comment: I think the problem is you don't return new copy of ```todos``` list in your ```reducer```

Comment: @TienDuong where exactly I should return it? I checked [the official examples](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition) but could not see the difference where it leads to a problem.

Comment: Can you create minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you manage state in your reducers. What you are doing is directly mutating an existing state, by doing `state = blah` which is against redux-priniciples. In order for `redux` to effectively recognize that a change has been made to the reducer, you must `return` a brand-new state object. Only then will your connected components re-render with the updated reducer data.

```
export default function todoReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ALL_TODOS_REQUESTED:
      return {
        ...state,
        todosLoading: true,
        todosError: null
      }
    case ALL_TODOS_RECEIVED:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: action.payload, 
        todosLoading: false, 
        todosError: null
      }
    case ALL_TODOS_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: null, 
        todosLoading: false, 
        todosError: action.payload
      }
    default:
       return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the correction and the explanation. I corrected my reducer but still have the same problem. I will try to do it all in HomePage container and see if it works, but if not then I have another problem which I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

Problems is how you are updating the state in your reducer :

if todos is Object

```
state = {...state, {todos: {...action.payload, ...state.todos }, todosLoading: false, todosError: null}}
```

if todos is list

```
state = {...state, {todos: state.todos.concat(action.payload) }, todosLoading: false, todosError: null}}
```